# how to scroll to a table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this,

```
   <div id="no-body">
    <table width="301">
          <tbody>
            <tr data-id="1"></tr>
            <tr data-id="2"></tr>
            <tr data-id="3"></tr> // so on
            <tr data-id="1000"></tr>
           </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Question**

**- How can I select tr using data-id**

**- How can I scroll to a tr 1000**

maybe using this ?

```
 $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
        },
       'slow');
```

**- Browser scroll is disabled, so I need to change this `('html,body')` with div ("no-body"), how can i do this ?**

Answer (score 2):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the `tr`.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('tr[data-id="1000"]').offset().top
},'slow');
```

```js
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('tr[data-id="1000"]').position().top+'px'
}, 'slow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="no-body">
  <table width="301">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="2"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="3"><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr data-id="1000"><td>1000</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 'tr[data-id="1000"]'

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  // wait for document to be fully loaded
    $( "tr" ).click(function( event ) {  // when any tr is clicked, pass the event
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( this ).offset().top
    }, 200);
    });
});
```

Using 'this' points to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: sorry, i can't use click function here